# Add left panel to bottom and top panel

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, panel

The code I have makes a top and bottom pannel I need to add a left panel as seem in the picture below:

My current code is:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title="myapp",size=(800,580))
        self.split_win =wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        self.top = wx.Panel(self.split_win ,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.bottom = wx.Panel(self.split_win ,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.split_win.SplitHorizontally(self.top,self.bottom,450)
        st1 = wx.StaticText(self.bottom, -1, "This is an example of static text", (20, 10))
        self.bottom.SetBackgroundColour('white')


app = wx.App()
frame=MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I need s left panel like the one in the picture where I can add a button and combobox.

[image]

I would also like to know if it is possible to have bottom and left and top panel without split?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to `sizers` in wx.python
Start here: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title="myapp",size=(800,580))
        self.top = wx.Panel(self, style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.bottom = wx.Panel(self ,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
        self.left = wx.Panel(self ,style = wx.SUNKEN_BORDER, size = (150,-1))
        st1 = wx.StaticText(self.bottom, -1, "This is an example of static text")
        st2 = wx.StaticText(self.left, -1, "Left Panel", (20, 10))
        self.bottom.SetBackgroundColour('white')

        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer1.Add(self.top,1,wx.EXPAND,5)
        sizer1.Add(self.bottom,1,wx.EXPAND,5)

        sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer2.Add(self.left,0,wx.EXPAND,5)
        sizer2.Add(sizer1,1,wx.EXPAND,5)

        self.SetSizer(sizer2)

app = wx.App()
frame=MainFrame(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]